# How to get strings values from numpy.ndarray of NPY_OBJECT

Tags: python, c, numpy

I am trying to get the names of columns in pandas.DataFrame using C API for python and numpy. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 7 and 64 bit python v3.6. I am able to get to the df.axes[1].values, however when I use PyArray_GETPTR1, the result seems to be invalid.

Here is my code:

```
// Initialize python
Py_SetPythonHome(L"C:\\Program Files\\Python36");
Py_Initialize();

// Initialize numpy
import_array();

// Build script
PyCompilerFlags flags;
flags.cf_flags = PyCF_SOURCE_IS_UTF8;
PyObject* compiled = Py_CompileStringFlags(
    "import numpy as np\n"
    "import pandas as pd\n"
    "def ReturnDataFrame():\n"
    "    df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})\n"
    "    return df\n",
    "test.py", Py_file_input, &flags
);
PyObject* codeModule = PyImport_ExecCodeModule("test.py", compiled);

// Call the function
PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(codeModule, "ReturnDataFrame");
PyObject* pReturn = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, nullptr);
Py_XDECREF(pFunc);

// Display column headers
PyObject* axes = PyObject_GetAttrString(pReturn, "axes");
PyObject* columnLabelsIndex = PyList_GET_ITEM(axes, 1);
PyObject* columns = PyObject_GetAttrString(columnLabelsIndex, "values");
const char* typeName = columns->ob_type->tp_name; // == "numpy.ndarray"
PyArrayObject* columnArray = (PyArrayObject*)columns;
int length = PyArray_DIMS(columnArray)[0];
int elementType = PyArray_TYPE(columnArray); // == NPY_OBJECT
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    PyObject* pElementValue = (PyObject*)PyArray_GETPTR1(columnArray, i);
    typeName = pElementValue->ob_type->tp_name; // invalid
    char* str = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pElementValue);
    std::cout << str;
    std::cout << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

I would appreciate any input on why these values are invalid.

Comment: Does `length` have the value you expected?

Comment: Yes, the length is 3